# How to use GNUPlot with dataset that is single-row separated with a comma

Tags: gnuplot

How can I use GNUplot with a single row dataset separated with commas and no spaces?

Example:

> 36.9,39.4,40.7,45.9,48.4,49.3,

Comment: What kind of plot do you want?  Are those numbers y coordinates, and if so what are the x coordinates?

Comment: Just a scatter plot, but I can handle that part on my own. These are Y coordinates and the x-axis is degrees 0-360.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ROWDATA << EOD
 36.9,39.4,40.7,45.9,48.4,49.3,
EOD

set datafile separator comma
row = 0
set yrange [0:50]
plot $ROWDATA matrix using 1:0 every :::row::row with points pt 7
```

Yes this is a really obscure command. Note that the program will interpret the trailing comma as an empty field and issue a non-fatal error message about missing matrix elements.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. Marked correct! Be well.